# Dynamic programming SPOJ problem SCUBADIV

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem from SPOJ, it's a dynamic programming problem, but I'm having trouble visualizing the recursive step. I believe it's similar to a knapsack, but here there are two constraints of Oxygen and Nitrogen.

Here is the link: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/SCUBADIV/

Comment: So, what is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work I think:

```
dp[i, j] = minimum weight needed such that we have i litres of oxygen and j litres 
           of nitrogen

dp[0, 0] = 0 and inf everywhere else
for each read cylinder k do
  for i = maxTotalOxygen down to oxygen[k] do
    for j = maxTotalNitrogen down to nitrogen[k]  do
      dp[i, j] = min(dp[i, j],                                       <- do not take cylinder k
                     dp[i - oxygen[k], j - nitrogen[k]] + weight[k])  <- take cylinder k 

Answer is the minimum dp[i, j] such that i >= RequiredOxygen and j >= RequiredNitrogen.
```

Note that the `for` loops **must** go from the max down to the values of the current cylinder, otherwise you allow a cylinder to be used more than once.

The problem constraints are very small and I think this should work.

Comment: I don't understand why the loop must go downwards. It should have the same effect if it was increasing right?

Comment: @user866098 - no, if it is increasing, then if you use cylinder `k` in the computation of a certain `[i, j]`, `k` could also have been used to compute `[i - oxygen[k], j - oxygen[k]]`, so it means you use it twice for `[i, j]`, which isn't allowed by the SPOJ problem (although a problem that does allow it is perfectly valid as well).

Comment: @User866098 - try running it manually on a small test. If you use a certain cylinder `x` where `oxygen[x] = 2` and `nitrogen[x] = 4` to find `dp[3, 5]` for example, you might also use it to find `dp[5, 9]` if you go ascendingly in the for loops, which you don't want to, because it would mean you used it twice for `dp[5, 9]`.

Comment: Shouldn't the inital values be 0 instead of infinity? Because: dp[5, 9] = min(dp[5,9],dp[3, 5] + weight[k]). If dp[3, 5] is infinity initially, then inf + weight[k] will be wrong right?

Comment: @user866098 - no, I think infinity is fine. It means you don't know the answer for `dp[3, 5]`. If you set it to 0 then you could have `dp[5, 9] = weight[k]`, which would be wrong. It needs to be infinity for the uninitialized values. In fact, the initialization isn't needed, it will happen anyway while running the main loops.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - thanks! It didn't show up for me because it wasn't a comment on my post. Fixed the base case.

Comment: No problem :) I'm guessing s/he just doesn't have enough rep to comment yet.

Comment: Assuming `maxTotalOxygen` is the sum of all the tanks' oxygen values, it is possible to create an extremely large search space by throwing in a very heavy tank with a very large amount of oxygen and nitrogen in it. It seems as though there should be a more efficient route since so much of the search space does not need to be explore (ala the triply-nested for loop).

Answer (score 4):

@IVlad very nice answer, thank you :)

However there's a catch:

The following should be removed :

```
dp[oxygen[i], nitrogen[i]] = weight[i] for each cylinder i and inf otherwise
```

And use this instead :

```
dp[0][0] = 0 and infinity everywhere else
```

The former statement is not a valid base case because it allows cylinders to be used twice.

How ?

The invariant of the outermost loop is that at the 
*N*
th iteration (of k), we try for every i,j to compute the minimum weight that can be achieved to obtain at least i oxygen and j nitrogen 
**using only cylinders 1 to N (each one used once)**

Consider the following test case where 2 oxygen and 2 nitrogen is required and we have 2 cylinders one with 1 ox 1 ni 1 weight, the other is 2 ox 2 ni 50 weight

2 2

2

1 1 1

2 2 50

The answer should be 50 simply because we can't use the 1st cylinder twice.

The base case that i claim wrong will fill d[1][1] = 1 before we even start the loops.
Then the loop starts with k=0 (use first cylinder and see if it helps in any entry), then d[2][2] will equal d[2-1][2-1]+1 = d[1][1] + 1 = 2

The final answer will be 2 units of weight because 1st cylinder was used twice due to the base case and this is not correct.